# RequestFactory and @OneToMany association

Tags: gwt, jpa, requestfactory

Iam stuck here! any help would be appreciated.

My case is that i have a @OneToMany association on my module.

```
 class Parent{
    @OneToMany(
       mappedBy="parent"
    )
    return List<Child> getChildren();
 }

 class Child{
   @ManyToOne
   return Parent getParent();
 }
```

The in the client side i want get get the whole object map.

i do this (AsyncDataProvider with a DataGrid as display):

```
 requestContext.getParents().with("children").fire(new Receiver<CallbackProxy>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(CallbackProxy response) {
                    display.setRowData(range.getStart(),response.getParents());
                    updateRowCount(response.getCount().intValue(), true);
                }
            });
```

My DAO its just querying the whole map.

```
 Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Parent.class);
 criteria.setFetchMode("children", FetchMode.JOIN);
 criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);

 /* we got all the map here on the server side */       

 Callback callback = new Callback();
 callback.setCount(count);
 callback.setParents(criteria.list());

 return callback;
```

But i cant get the childs. The list of them are null. Please note iam using with("children")

Thank you.

Comment: My problem is i am wraping my result into a ValueProxy and seems that with("") look for the property into the result proxy.

Answer (score 0):

RequestContext.getParents() seem to return CallbackProxy but not Parent. So the with clause should look like "parents.childs".

Btw, why not call them "children"? Just for the case the GWT guys add a grammar checker one day :-)

Comment: Hehe ;) i was just using random names as example. Sorry